# Spring - correct use of @Autowired with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand what is wrong with my MVC application, as I am not much expert with the Spring ecosystem.

I want to create a REST endpoint (UserEndpoint) for user management. The endpoint should use a UserService that, in turn, uses a DAO (UserDAO). I am stuck at how I inject the dependency for the UserService in the UserEndpoint. I have been trying to use @Autowired, but when I do I get the following error:

```
2016-07-01 16:09:59.995  INFO 2080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3794 ms
2016-07-01 16:10:00.211  INFO 2080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-01 16:10:00.222  INFO 2080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-01 16:10:00.374  WARN 2080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEndpoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.endpoint.UserEndpoint.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: simpleUserService,getUserService
2016-07-01 16:10:00.381  INFO 2080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-07-01 16:10:00.412 ERROR 2080 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEndpoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.endpoint.UserEndpoint.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: simpleUserService,getUserService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.ObfuscatedMessageStore.main(ObfuscatedMessageStore.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.endpoint.UserEndpoint.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: simpleUserService,getUserService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: simpleUserService,getUserService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2016-07-01 16:10:00.416  INFO 2080 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Users/antonio/dev/IdeaProjects/ObfuscatedMessageStore/target/classes/, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.4/jackson-core-2.5.4.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.5.4/jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/Users/antonio/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

UserEndpoint.java:

```
package com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.endpoint;

import com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.domain.User;
import com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@Controller
public class UserEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users",
            method = POST,
            produces = "application/json")
    public void createUser(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        User user = new User(name);
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{uuid}",
            method = GET,
            produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") int uuid) {
        return userService.getUser(uuid);
    }
}
```

UserService.java:

```
public interface UserService {

    boolean addUser(User user);

    User getUser(int uuid);
}
```

SimpleUserService.java:

```
@Service
public class SimpleUserService implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int uuid) {
        return userDao.getUser(uuid);
    }

}
```

MvcConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.diferdin.tests.obfuscatedmessagestore")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserService getUserService() {
        return new SimpleUserService();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.diferdin.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>obfuscatedmessagestore</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!--<springboot.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</springboot.version>-->
    <spring-mvc.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring-mvc.version>
    <spring-aop.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring-aop.version>
    <spring-context.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring-context.version>
    <jackson-core.version>2.5.4</jackson-core.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.5.4</jackson-databind.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-mvc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have seen questions asking about the same type of error, however they all use XML config files whereas in my case configuration is programmatic through a java file -- may well be wrong, as I said I am no expert.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Why do you have both a component scanned `@Service` and a `@Bean` for that class?

Comment: It was suggested in a tutorial I followed, my understanding is that the Bean is used to inject, while the ComponentScan tells Spring where to look for components -- in my case, SimpleUserService I return. As I said, I am not an expert...

Comment: Also, you need to autowire userDao field inside the service implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'd like to ask where is the exact duplicate question to this, so that I can go check it...

Comment: Refresh this page. The link will be at the top.

Comment: @aviad thanks. I am aware. My current error lies with the injection in UserEndpoint, which is ahead of the use of UserDAO, and I didn't want to complicate things further by adding more Autowire -- will do once I meet an error that hints at UserDAO...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe the error is identical but the context different; I do not have an XML config file and my understanding is that MvcConfiguration is used instead....

Comment: `@Bean` and `<bean>` are two equivalent ways to declare beans. You've declared two beans of the same type. One because of the component scanned `@Service` and another because of the `@Bean` method (if you were using XML, because of a `<bean>` declaration). Just don't declare two beans.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. If I remove the Bean annotation in my class, I get a different exception:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z`

I have seen users suggesting conflicts in the maven dependencies for this type of exception, I've included my pom.xml in the question for clarity.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have one. Yes. Your versions are off. Check which spring boot version is compatible with core Spring.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. I'll ask the above as a different question.